# Install Java command line - webupd8team PPA DISCONTINUED

Tags: java, oracle

Java can't be installed from webupd8team PPA since the Oracle JDK License has changed for releases starting April 16, 2019:

https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

> Oracle Java downloads now require logging in to an Oracle account to
>   download Java updates, like the latest Oracle Java 8u211 / Java SE
>   8u212. Because of this I cannot update the PPA with the latest Java
>   (and the old links were broken by Oracle).

How to install Java 8 JDK in command line mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty howto to switch out java 8 from webupd8 ppa with Amazon's OpenJDK8-based Coretto:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/generic-linux-install.html